# NFS export of other mounts in the tree

Tags: nfs, redhat

I have a filesystem under /var/hudson/jobs which is exported thus:

```
   /var/hudson/jobs *(ro,no_root_squash,nohide)
```

I regularly mount new LVM volumes under that directory structure (say, /var/hudson/jobs/A/2222) and want to be able to mount these from my client nodes.

In the configuration above, I get the following error if I try

```
request to export directory /var/hudson/jobs/A/2222 below nearest filesystem /var/hudson/jobs
```

I could live with mounting all of /var/hudson/jobs on the client but I can't see any content under /var/hudson/jobs/A/2222 when I do.  This suggests to met that nohide isn't working as expected, though this isn't a surprise given the caveats in the man page.

How can I see this other filesystems from the NFS client without adding a line to /etc/exports for each one?

This is on RHEL5.

Answer (score 1):

From `exports`(5):

> The nohide option is currently only effective on single host exports.  It does not work reliably with netgroup, subnet, or wildcard exports.

You should go with whichever one of "duplicate exports lines, one per client" or "lots of exports+mounts" is less work in your situation.  I'd expect that the former is probably going to work better.